# concatenate words from two separate files

Tags: php, scripting

I am trying to concatenate words from a file with words from another file. However when I run the script I get a full output of the first file, then the output of the second file, then I see that the execution does not complete so I am stuck in an infinite loop. This is my code:

```
include 'passgen.txt';
include 'mycharset.txt';

$lines=file('passgen.txt');
$additions=file('mycharset.txt');

foreach($lines as $line){
        foreach($additions as $addition){

        $newPasswords=$line . $addition;

        }
}
file_put_contents('newPasswords.txt', print_r($newPasswords, true));
```

passgen.txt content example:

```
stack
5tack
St4ck
...
```

mycharset.txt content example:

```
1
1!
2
2!
```

Expected results of what I am trying to achieve:

```
stack1
stack1!
stack2
stack2!
5tack1
5tack1!
...
```

**EDIT:**

adding full code from Jay answer:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
include 'passgen.txt';
include 'mycharset.txt';

$lines=file('passgen.txt');
$additions=file('mycharset.txt');

foreach($lines as $start) {
    foreach($additions as $end) {
        file_put_contents('newPasswords2.txt', $start.$end ."\r\n", FILE_APPEND);

    }
}
?>
```

SAMPLE OUTPUT from Jay answer:

```
St4ck
6!3

St4ck
6!4

St4ck
6!5
```

I tried to remove the \r\n but still does not append the 6!5 to the word in the desired format below:

```
St4ck6!4
St4ck6!5
...
```

Comment: _newPasswords.txt_ ? Hmm... don't do that!

Comment: I really hate that you're creating some default password text. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I am using a weak password finder and I need a custom list of password to compare if hashes are weak.

Comment: It looks more like a rainbow table generator, albeit a small one.

Comment: Isn't there any other way you can find a weak password. Creating two txts and combining them means it's all on you. If your imagination is weak a weak password will get through.

Comment: @GreenRoof Did any of the provided solution work for you?

Comment: @mega6382 I tried your solution yesterday. For the first iteration of file2 it "kind of" works: it takes each line of file1 and adds each line of file2, but as soon as file2 ends the first iteration it keeps looping through file1 words without breaking output in a new line and without adding file2 lines. So I am afraid it does not work.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Thanks for the warm welcome! I will try your solution on Monday and if it works I will mark the answer as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just creating a line, so you will not get an array as `$newPasswords` is overwritten on each iteration. What I did was place the concatenated words into an array (`$word_array`). You can then loop through the array easily and place into a text file:

### EDIT

Added the `trim()` function to account for any whitespace characters in the text files we may not be aware of:

```
$file1 = ['stack','5tack','St4ck'];
$file2 = ['1','1!','2'];

$word_array = array();
foreach($file1 as $start) {
    foreach($file2 as $end) {
        $word_array[] = trim($start).trim($end); 
    }
}
print_r($word_array);
```

Returns:

```
Array

(
    [0] => stack1
    [1] => stack1!
    [2] => stack2
    [3] => 5tack1
    [4] => 5tack1!
    [5] => 5tack2
    [6] => St4ck1
    [7] => St4ck1!
    [8] => St4ck2
)
```

Now you can put these in your text file like this:

```
foreach($word_array as $word) {
    file_put_contents('newPasswords.txt', $word."\r\n");
}
```

Having said that I caution you against using this for password generation for any reason. You're essentially creating a rainbow table based on your comment:

> I am using a weak password finder and I need a custom list of password to compare if hashes are weak.

You'd be better off providing the users with a password strength indicator that would encourage them to create strong passwords.

### Shortening the process...

You could shorten the process entirely by writing to the file during the loop, which would require no arrays:

```
foreach($file1 as $start) {
    foreach($file2 as $end) {
        file_put_contents('newPasswords.txt', trim($start).trim($end) ."\r\n", FILE_APPEND); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Your shortened process is wrong. 1st it will override previous data on every iteration, second `'\r\n'` single quotes will not escape the new lines. And third `(` is never closed.

Comment: If `file_put_contents()` appends (changed), then this will work (corrected the syntax error). The newline carriage return doesn't have to be interpolated at this point, as you want to write it to the file as part of the text. I'll change the quoting to make you more comfortable.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I tried your answer and it works with no PHP error, however id does not give the desired output. I edited my question with the full code and a sample output from your suggestion.

Comment: *smacks forehead* - There must be something going on in your text files, like line breaks, that we're not thinking about. See my updated code.

Comment: Glad to help and apologies for not thinking about your text more thoroughly @GreenRoof

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`fgets()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) function to read from a file line by line. Then you can concatenate that.
So something like:

```
$count = 0;
while($word = fgets($lines, 4096)){
$word = $word . additions[$count];
echo $word;
$count++;
}
```